# vercel deployed website doesn't update when github is updated

Tags: express, deployment, backend, vercel, cache-control

I have been facing the same problem in every project that I upload on vercel. When I commit and push some changes in a github repo connected with the vercel deployment, the vercel dashboard shows the new deployment and everything works fine on the vercel dashboard. But when I access the website with the domain, I don't see any changes I made.

Some people on the internet say its due to caching so I did this in my index.js file :

```
app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store').sendFile(path.resolve('dist', 'index.html'))
);
```

but this doesn't solve it.
then I tried :

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")), {
    setHeaders: function (res, path, stat) {
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    }
})
```

and even this didn't work.
I am not finding a solution for this problem anywhere on the internet.